# POST hangs the script and does not execute the code after submitting the form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem. I have a credit card form, where the customer will fill out the data and be submitted to the bank's evaluation. However, it should perform some operations ** before ** of the function that will send its data to the payment gateway.
I will illustrate a step by step of what should be happening:

1. User fills card details;
2. Send the form;
3. User receive the response "Please wait, reviewing data";
4. User received a "Payment approved" or "Payment denied" response;

But step 3 is not running. Here is my code:

```
$('#credit_card_form').submit(function() {
    $.post($("#credit_card_form").attr('action'), $("#credit_card_form").serialize(), function(data){
        $("#return_form").html(data);
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

The POST is sent to here:

```
if ($_POST['f'] == 'pay_credit_card') {
    $brand_card = $_POST['card_brand'];
    $number_card = $_POST['card_number'];
    $exp_month = $_POST['card_valid_month'];
    $exp_year = $_POST['card_valid_year'];
    $cod_security = $_POST['card_security'];
    $name_card = $_POST['card_name'];

    // Example - just to illustrate that i have a check here
    if ($_POST['card_number'] == '') {
        echo "Fill the field X"
        return false;
    }

    // d_none = display: none;
    echo "<script>$('#processing_card').removeClass('d_none'); $('#div_credit_card_form').addClass('d_none');</script>";
    $return_gateway = CS_MundiPagg($brand_card, $number_card, $exp_month, $exp_year, $cod_security, $name_card);
    if ($return_gateway == 'Captured') {        
        echo "<script>$('#success_card').removeClass('d_none'); $('#modal-close').addClass('d_none');</script>";
    }
}
```

The script goes through "echo" above of CS_MundiPagg() and goes straight to the answer, at the end of the script. As if it "crashes" the script after the user submits the form and bring only the final answer (payment approved or not).

I've tried almost everything, I'm not finding a solution. Is there hope at the end of the tunnel?

Comment: Please also show the html form page you are trying to post, I had a similar problem before and thanks to that I found a bug in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you closed your `<form>` `</form>` tags I had this problem before with serialize plugin, thanks to that I found a bug in jquery. Also make sure to use `$(document).ready(function ()`

Also change your code to

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
//replace to buttonid click function 
$('#credit_card_form').click(function() {
    var combinedData = $("#credit_card_form").serialize();
    $.post(
                        "page.php",
                        combinedData
                 ).done(function(data) {
               //alert("Successfully submitted!");


                        $("#result").html(data);
                 }).fail(function () {
                          //alert("Error submitting forms!");
                 })

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you receive answer from your AJAX call when everything is done - after your PHP code receives the answer from the routine CS_MundiPagg().

To display a "Please wait!" message you should do it in the browser before sending the query.

You could try it this way:

```
$('#credit_card_form').submit(function() {
    var myFormData = $("#credit_card_form").serialize();
    var myWaitMsg = "Please wait ... <br><img src='img/waiting.gif'>";

    $("#return_form").html(myWaitMsg);
    $.post(
          $("#credit_card_form").attr('action'), 
          myFormData, 
          function(data){
                  $("#return_form").html(data);
          }
    ); 
    return false;
});
```